# ¿Cómo puedo llamar con el evento de un botón a un modal que se encuentra en una vista parcial?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

Les comento un poco de mi problema, deseo mantener mi código lo mas limpio que se pueda, entonces deseo llamar a un formulario **modal**  que se encuentra en una vista parcial(con la estructura de un modal) desde el evento de un botón.

Deseo llamar desde el **Index.cshtml** a la vista **CreatCampaign.cshtml**(que es mi formulario modal)

El proyecto se esta desarrollando en **asp.net core** sdk 2.2

> **CampaignController.cs** este es el controlador de mi proyecto

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Prueba2LTE.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Prueba2LTE.Controllers {
  public class CampaignController: Controller {
    public IActionResult Index() {
      return View();
    }

    public IActionResult CreateCampaign() {
      return PartialView("CreateCampaign");
    }
  }
}
```

> **Index.cshtml**

```html
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
<section class="content container-fluid">
  <h2>CAMPAING MODAL</h2>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action(" CreateCampaign ", "Campaign ")'">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

  <!-- Modal -->

</section>
```

> **CreatCampaign.cshtml**

```html
<section class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Campaña</h4>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombreCampaña" class="control-label">Nombre de la campaña: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCampaña" placeholder="Nombre de la campaña...">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descripcionCampaña">Descripcion: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionCampaña" placeholder="Descripcion...">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rango de Fecha:</label>

                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Por favor les pido su ayuda, tal vez estoy importando mal mis librerías (AdminLTE) o lo estoy llamando mal al modal, soy novato en este lenguaje, les quedaré muy agradecido, Gracias.

PD. Tal vez desean ver más de mi código, estaré atento para modificar la publicación y subir para mostrarles mi código y sea más clara la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tienes 2 errores.
Para que puedas llamar tu modal, debe de existir en tu html, algo que aun no existe ya que esta dentro de tu vista parcial.

Y para poder llamar tu vista parcial dentro de tu vista padre debes de especificarle en donde se va a generar. Lo que estas haciendo ahorita es que cuando le picas al boton te regresa la vista parcial como si fuera una vista padre.

Tu `button` dice lo siguiente:

```
data-target="#myModal"
```

Quiere decir que cuando le des click buscara ese elemento de html para desplegarlo (Aun no existe)

En este caso yo veo varias opciones dependiendo de tu necesidad. Dices que quieres mantener el codigo limpio, asi que la mas facil seria lo siguiente:

```
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
<section class="content container-fluid">
  <h2>CAMPAING MODAL</h2>

@await Html.PartialAsync("CreateCampaign")

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action(" CreateCampaign ", "Campaign ")'">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

  <!-- Modal -->

</section>
```

Notese que agregue un:

**@await Html.PartialAsync("CreateCampaign")**

Esto lo que hara es llamar automaticamente tu `Action` cuando cargues tu vista padre que regresa tu partial View y la renderizara en esa linea.

Y en tu boton solamente eliminas el llamado del click

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
```

Hay otras opciones, podrias usar un `load` tambien o un `Ajax`, pero creo que esta te funciona bien para lo que necesitas.

Comment: Te agradezco por haberte dado el tiempo de responder, eres muy amable, pero te pido ayuda en este error cuando pongo @Html.Action("CreateCampaign"), mes sale el siguiente error 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension method overload 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IUrlHelper'

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, olvide que era Core

Comment: Gracias amigo, en serio me ayudaste bastante.... :)

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta correcta.
Te doy un pequeño consejo.
Como diria el Tio Ben.
Un gran poder como las vistas parciales, conllevan una gran responsabilidad.
Es decir, no abusar.